# How Can I Call a Class Method From a Different Class in Python?

Tags: python, websocket, serial-port

I have a Raspberry Pi with:

- Serial interface over Xbee to Arduinos
- WebSocket server interface to
  a Web page (html/javascript)

I wrote a Python script to coordinate communication (I'm brand new to Python). It contains:

- Serial interface class
- WebSocket interface class

I'm trying to relay data between the Web page and the Arduinos. Specifically, I'm trying to **call the "send" method in the Websocket class from the Serial class**, and to **call the "send" method in the Serial class from the WebSocket class**.

I've spent a lot of time reading and researching but I just can't figure it out. Here's my code the way it stands now. The specific error I get is "sendSocket() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given).

```
# server.py

DEBUG = True;

import serial
import time
import sys
import json
import os
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task

# I think I need these for the instances?
global socket, serial

# ---------------------------------
# WebSocket Interface
# ---------------------------------
class HaSocketProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    # I'm not sure of any other way to incorporate the instance
    global serial

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def onConnect(self, request):
        debug("Client connected")

    def onOpen(self):
        debug("WebSocket Server Open")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if not isBinary:
            payload = payload.decode('utf8')
            debug("Incoming socket message: {} -- Writing as-is to xbee".format(payload))
            # Here is where I'm trying to send the data I received out the serial port using the SerialInterface class method
            self.sendSerial(serial, payload)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        debug("WebSocket connection closed - {}".format(reason))

    # Socket server sending over socket    
    def send(self, message):
        self.sendMessage(message)

    # Here is where I'm trying to link them 
    @classmethod
    def sendSerial(SerialInterface, message):
        SerialInterface.send(message)

# ---------------------------------
# Serial Interface
# ---------------------------------
class SerialInterface:
    xbee = None
    # trying to iunclude the instance
    global socket

    def __init__(self, devname, baud, to):
        self.xbee = serial.Serial(devname, baud, timeout=to)
        debug(self.xbee)

    def check(self):
        incoming = None
        # will timeout if there's no data to be read
        incoming = self.xbee.readline().strip()
        if incoming != None and incoming != "":
            self.handle(incoming)

    # serial send over serial
    def send(self, message):
        self.xbee.write(message)
        self.xbee.write("\n")

    # here is where i'm trying to link them    
    @classmethod
    def sendSocket(HaSocketProtocol, message):
        HaSocketProtocol.send(message)        

    def handle(self, incoming):
        debug("Incoming serial: {}".format(incoming))

        # ...
        # my logic is in here that leads to several instances where I
        # create a command string that I send over the serial port
        # ...

        socketMessage = "ArduinoCommand"
        self.sendSocket(socket, socketMessage)

# ------------------------------
# main
# ------------------------------
def main():
    global socket, serial

    serial = SerialInterface('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, 1)
    socket = HaSocketProtocol()

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = socket

    # check Serial port for data every 1 second
    ser = task.LoopingCall(serial.check)
    ser.start(1.0)

    reactor.listenTCP(9000, factory)
    reactor.run()

def debug(msg):
    if DEBUG:
        print "{}\n".format(msg)    


main()
```

Comment: Note that variables (and arguments) start with a lowercase letter by convention

Comment: there are multiple issues with this code. e.g. `factory.protocol = socket` is wrong, since it assign an instance of `HaSocketProtocol`, not the class. then `HaSocketProtocol` overrides the constructor, but does not call the base constructor. then this whole class method thing: it won't work. for each connected WebSocket client there is a separate server protocol instance. to which of the possibly many connected clients do you want to send out data coming over serial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this question is really about how you implement the Autobahn framework, not really about how you program in Python. For me, it was easier to rewrite it in JavaScript and put it on Node.js. Runs great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a @classmethod "decorator" over the HaSocketProtocol.send() method, just like you have for a few others.

Answer (score 0):

class method gets the class automatically:

```
@classmethod
def myMethod(cls):
   pass
```

That's why you are getting this error - 2 arguments + cls = 3. But the method takes only two.
So you have to add "cls" argument to your sendSocket method

```
 @classmethod
    def sendSocket(cls, HaSocketProtocol, message):
        HaSocketProtocol.send(message)
```

If you don't really need cls in your method, replace @classmethod with @staticmethod

P.S. check other class methods

Answer (score 0):

Your classmethod should look like this:

```
@classmethod
def sendSocket(cls, hsockprotocol, message):
    hsockprotocol.send(message)
```

Note the change of the second parameter. It should be just a variable, not a class reference.